# How to get table with single corner cut in each cell?

Tags: tables, cellcolor

What I am trying to achieve is a table in which each cell has bottom right of its corners cut away like this:
[image]

The cut-away portion is supposed to be of static size. How to achieve such result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. That environment is similar to the standard `{tabular}` (of the package `array`) but creates also PGF/Tikz nodes under the rows, columns and cells. Then, it's possible to use those nodes with Tikz. In the following code, I use Tikz and those nodes to creates small white triangles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz,ifthen}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}[hvlines-except-borders,rules={color=white,width=1pt}]
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolor{red!15}{1}
  \rowcolor{blue!15}{2-}
\Body
  some text & other & other & other \\
  some text & other & other & other \\
  some text & other & other & other \\
  some text & other & other & other \\
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture}[color = white]
  \foreach \i in {2,...,\inteval{\value{iRow}+1}} 
    {
      \foreach \j in {2,...,\inteval{\value{jCol}+1}}
        { 
          % for technical reasons, the last column needs a special treatment: 
          % we translate by the width of the rules
          \ifthenelse{\j>\value{jCol}}
          { \fill ([xshift=1pt]\i-|\j) -- ++ (0,2mm) -- ++ (-2mm,-2mm) -- cycle ; }
          { \fill (\i-|\j) -- ++ (0,2mm) -- ++ (-2mm,-2mm) -- cycle ; }
        }
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because of the PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]